# WCF service errors

Tags: c#, wcf

Ok SO community.  I've got a bizarre one for you today.  I'm completely stumped, and Googling isn't finding me useful results.  Here's to hoping the best community out there can have some ideas.

**The Problem**

I am getting the following two errors in my web service:

**Error 1:**

```
11/17/2015 1:32:49 PM - GetGoogleFlightTrackerImage ERROR: 
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(Stream stream)
   at GeoMapping.TrackerImage.DrawImage()
   at GeoMapping.GeoMappingService.GetGoogleFlightTrackerImage(String TailNumber, Int32 xRes, Int32 yRes, IEnumerable`1 AdditionalLayers, Boolean DisplayFlightPlan, MapType MapType)
```

**Error 2:**

```
11/17/2015 1:22:22 PM - GetGoogleFlightTrackerImage ERROR: 
System.Net.WebException: 
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)
   at GeoMapping.TrackerImage.DrawImage()
   at GeoMapping.GeoMappingService.GetGoogleFlightTrackerImage(String TailNumber, Int32 xRes, Int32 yRes, IEnumerable`1 AdditionalLayers, Boolean DisplayFlightPlan, MapType MapType)
```

Now, I understand that Error 1 is a very generic error, and can be thrown for many different reasons.  One of the reasons I assumed to be an offender was not disposing of Bitmaps properly.  I have since gone through all of the code and disposed of all objects appropriately.  Still receiving the error unfortunately.  As for Error 2, I understand that error to mean that the service has crashed, stopped, is currently busy, or something of that nature.

**The Bizarre Part**

Here's where it gets weird.  When I log into the server, to look at the event logs and see the errors, they stop.  Completely. This has been happening for a couple weeks now.  The service can run just fine for a long time, and then it will start getting these errors.  Maybe it happens overnight, and goes on for hours.  When I come in, I can log in to the server, and they immediately stop.  Also, it's not just my login that makes it work.  ANY login to the server makes it work again.  No IIS resets, no app pool restarts, or anything.  It just works.  And the last entry in the event viewer is always my windows logon.  Then no more errors.

So, I ask all of you, is there something I'm missing?  What is it about me logging into the server that can miraculously fix these errors?  My only initial thought is that the HD is going to sleep, but seeing how we have constant writes to the event viewer, and constant attempts at reading images on the HD, I wouldn't think this is it.  Any ideas?

**My Server Environment**

OS:  Windows Server 2008 Datacenter

Server Type:  VM

RAM: 16GB

Comment: And would the person who downvoted and voted to close this issue care to elaborate why?  I would gladly fix my question if there's a problem.

Comment: Error 1 - My guess is that the stream you're trying to draw from is null.  Error 2 - This looks like the remote server (Google I'm assuming) is refusing the connection from your site.  It could be that something bad is being passed to Google.  But I do know you should start at the GetGoogleFlightTrackerImage method.

Comment: What type of machine is the server? VM or physical? Could it be that something related to the network (network adapter / driver etc.) goes offline and gets a 'kick in the pants' from you RDP'ing to the server which makes the issue go away? Can you move the service to another server to see if it exhibits the same behavior?

Comment: @user469104, I have updated the question to reflect my server environments.  I'll look into the network adapter/driver.  That's a good idea.  As for a second server, this is actually happening on 2 servers (same specs) that both run this web service.

Comment: Update:  Looked into the network adapter/driver, but this doesn't seem to be the issue.  It's currently set to never go to sleep.  Still searching for an answer to this.  Thanks for the help so far though!